# SQL transpose/Pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

Im a stranger to SQL, I have somehow managed to get this table out but, its still far away from what I need. My table looks like,

```
    Location   Bus        Type        Colour  Count Capacity
 1. hartford   volvo      20 Seater   Red     10    5000cc
 2. hartford   ford       10 seater   blue    12    2000cc
 3. hartford   Merc       20 seater   green   12    2000cc
 4. kansas     lambo      16 Seater   Red     13    1000cc
 5. kansas     banbo      15 Seater   blue    13    1000cc
 6. kansas     babho      17 Seater   green   13    1000cc
```

I want to change the layout to

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMUgf.png

Please suggest me how can I get the desired layout.Im trying to use pivot function in sql

Comment: Just google "<your database name> pivot".  For instance, "MySQL pivot", "SQL Server pivot", "Postgres pivot", "Oracle pivot".  The results should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @gordon:Im doing the same as we speak. But, I need some expert advice. Im still working on my sql basics and the problem at hand is out of my reach